# mvn ear pluging generates 3 artifacts instead of 2

Tags: maven, ear, generate

I want "the trick" in maven to avoid the "default generation" of artifacts.
I have a pom.xml which generates three artifacts instead of two.

In my pom.xml file I have:

...

```
  <packaging>ear</packaging>
  <name>project-ear</name>
```

...

And here the important part:

```
 <plugins>      
      <plugin>
        <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
        <artifactId>maven-ear-plugin</artifactId>
        <version>2.10</version>
        <executions>            
            <execution>
                <id>fija</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>ear</goal>
                    <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>fe</finalName>
```

... and same for movil...

```
<executions>            
            <execution>
                <id>fija</id>
                <phase>package</phase>
                <goals>
                    <goal>ear</goal>
                    <goal>generate-application-xml</goal>
                </goals>
                <configuration>
                    <finalName>fe</finalName>
```

The generated artifacts were:

- fe-fija.ear
- fe-movil.ear
- project-ear-1.0.0.ear

But I don´t want "project-ear-1.0.0.ear" to be generated, only the "executions" part
I´ve seen here in SO the trick but I cannot found again.

Comment: remove all the executions...only define the version of the maven-ear-plugin (Use a more recent version)... by using the `<packaging>ear</packaging>` it's automatically done...

Comment: I cant remove the executions, becase it must generate the: fe-fija.ear and fe-movil.ear

Comment: @y.z Why do you have these executions? Which problem are you trying to solve with them? Note that you are probably better off using multi-module instead.

Comment: Please explain what are the differences between those parts fija, movil? The "default" generation is done based on the packaging ear and default binding... furthermore and based on the artifactId...

Comment: @JFabianMeier I have these execution by project requeriments, it´s a somewhat easy form to have two different URL for te project and have diferent behavior in some part/calls to beans with the same .xhtml inside the ear.

Comment: @khmarbaise then how can I disable the default binding? I don´t see necesary to explain the differences between "movil" and "fija", maybe it´s a better architecture design, but believe me that is somewhat good the actual design.

Comment: @y.z Better create a multi-module project with one module for each of the EARs you want to generate.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

After a lot of search, and thanks to ChatGpt I found the solution:

Just above the project name one should change ear to pom,
so te final solution is:

pom
project-ear